# Putting a Dictionary into a HashMap Issue with duplicate words

Tags: java, hashmap

I am currently teaching myself Java and decided I wanted to build a simple program that reads a .txt file that has nearly a complete dictionary and then places those entries into a HashMap so a user can input a word and then receives the definition of the word.

Here is the method that places the lines into the HashMap. My issue is with words like desert or desert and I understand you cannot have duplicates with HashMaps(Did not consider words with same spelling when I began that). My real questions I suppose is there another data structure I could work with to create the same result?  I am not looking for a do this and how to do it type answer. Just a hint like use x data structure would be amazing.  [Here](https://github.com/granim/wordSearch/tree/master/dictionary) is the link to 
the gitrepo if that is even needed.  Thank you in advance!!

```
public static void createMap(File file) {
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);) {
            hold = bufferedReader.readLine();

            while (hold != null) {

                if (bufferedReader.readLine() != "") {
                    stringArray = hold.split(" ");
                    diction.put(stringArray[0].toLowerCase(), hold);
                    hold = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry could not find the proper file " + file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry there was a problem with the program ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not that I am aware of; however, I believe a Hash Map could still be useful to you. The problem you are having is that repeated keys are being replaced is that correct?

Comment: Yea I really just wanted to build something to work with hashmaps but was running into problems with words and phrases that were duplicates.  The answer down below is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Hashmap<String, List<String>>` with the key being the word and the list containing the different meanings.

Small code example:

```
// to create an empty dictionary
HashMap<String, List<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

// to add the word "exampleWord", with meaning "exampleMeaning"
if ( !dictionaryMap.containsKey("exampleWord")) {
    dictionaryMap.put("exampleWord",new ArrayList<String>());
}
dictionaryMap.get("exampleWord").add("exampleMeaning");
```

Note that you should wrap the add-a-word-with-a-meaning snippet inside a method.

Comment: Thank you I had tried something similar to this but did not think to change the value from a String to a list, makes complete sense now. This should work perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using a `TreeMap<String, List<String> >` instead of a `HashMap`. Yes, my answer is very similar to [Bart's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51364685/15472), since both `HashMap` and `TreeMap` implement very similar APIs. However, for a real-world dictionary,

- It is often useful to see what words are near to the one you are looking for. This can help you with misspellings.
- The ends of forms for related words varies a lot more than their beginning. So sorting by the start of the word is useful during lookup. For example, for most verbs, only the infinitives are listed.

This would allow the following behavior:

```
 /**
  * Shows the definitions of all words that start with the given letters.
  * @param start of the word
  */
 public void listStartingWith(String start) {
    // note that "zzz" does not occur in English, and z is the last letter;
    // therefore, start+zzz occurs after all valid words that start with 'start'
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : map.subMap(start, start+"zzz")) {
       showDefinition(e.getKey());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program that does what you want. You should use a map of type `Map<String, List<String>>` so a string can map to several definitions. When you come across a word, check if the word is already in the dictionary. If so, append to the list of definitions, otherwise make a new list.

I also changed the return type so the function always returns a map so you are not modifying static variables.

I used a `java.util.TreMap` instead because it maintains order. You list happens to be sorted, but in the event that you word list were not sorted, than the hashmap would not keep your words sorted in alphabetical order. The Tree map will.

Lastly, reading a file line by line is a lot easier with `java.util.Scanner`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Dictionary {

  public static Map<String, List<String>> createMap(File file) throws Exception {

    Scanner      fileReader;
    int          firstSpace;
    String       line;
    String       word;
    String       definition;
    List<String> definitions;
    Map<String, List<String>> dictionary;

    // Use a tree map to keep sorted
    // even if your word list is not sorted
    dictionary = new TreeMap<>();
    fileReader = new Scanner(file);

    // Loop through file line by line
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {

      // Get each line
      line = fileReader.nextLine();

      // Avoid empty lines
      if (!line.equals("")) {

        // Split the word and definition
        // by finding the index of the first space
        firstSpace = line.indexOf(' ');
        word       = line.substring(0, firstSpace);
        definition = line.substring(firstSpace + 1);

        // If the dictionary already contains
        // the word, then add to the list of
        // definitions
        if (dictionary.containsKey(word)) {

          definitions = dictionary.get(word);

          definitions.add(definition);

        // Otherwise make a new list
        // of definitions and insert it's
        // first entry
        } else {

          definitions = new LinkedList<>();

          definitions.add(definition);
        }

        // Insert / updated the word and
        // it's list of definitions
        dictionary.put(word, definitions);
      }


    }

    // Close when done
    fileReader.close();

    return dictionary;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file;
    Map<String, List<String>> dictionary;

    // Read file into map
    // then print each entry
    // on to a new line
    try {

      file       = new File("dictionary.txt");
      dictionary = createMap(file);

      Iterable entries = dictionary.entrySet();

      for (Object entry : entries) {

        System.out.println(entry);
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

      System.exit(1);
    }

  }

}
```

Input (shorter version of your file):

```
A prefix (also an- before a vowel sound) not, without (amoral). [greek]

Aa  abbr 1 automobile association. 2 alcoholics anonymous. 3 anti-aircraft.

Aa some other stuff
Aa more stuff

Aardvark  n. Mammal with a tubular snout and a long tongue, feeding on termites. [afrikaans]
```

Output:

```
A=[ prefix (also an- before a vowel sound) not, without (amoral). [greek]]
Aa=[  abbr 1 automobile association. 2 alcoholics anonymous. 3 anti-aircraft.,  some other stuff,  more stuff]
Aardvark=[  n. Mammal with a tubular snout and a long tongue, feeding on termites. [afrikaans]]
```